# Wordpress theme with second language

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I didn't find any learn for Multi-Lingual !

> 1.How to use function `_e()` ?
>
> 2.What's text_domain ? How can i set text_domain ?

**e.g:**

`_e('Mine','text_domain')`

in english returns "Mine"

in example language is "imja"

> How to set "imja" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text_domain` is a distinction inside WordPress that allows you to see which plugin or theme text comes from. The text domain can be any string that you want but as a best practice it should be a machine name of the theme or plugin you are building.

So if I had a plugin named MyPlugin I would translate text using any of the WordPress translation functions like:

`print __("Translateable Text", "MyPlugin");
_e("Text that is translated then echoed", "MyPlugin");`

For WordPress to render these strings in another language, in WordPress 4.0 and above, you can change the language at `Settings > General > Site Language` and your site will show the text in that language if available.

You will need language files for the language that you wish to change to, and if a plugin or theme doesn't offer a translation for your chosen language it will be rendered in the default language.

There are many tools and plugins for editing the .po/.mo files that hold the translations in WordPress. Some of those can be found in the [WordPress translation handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/other/).